# Is there a way to have auto width on larger screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 I want to use col-xs-12 on an element but on all other displays I want the element and any following elements to use auto width on any larger displays.
I think the answer is media queries but I couldn't find any answers on this issue.
maybe something like col-sm-auto

EDIT:  I hope I can properly explains this.

Let's say you have an input and a couple of labels on the page
[image: large display example]

Now in xs view I want the labels to drop to a new line, to do that I can set the input to col-xs-12 but that will not give the required results on large displays

[image: xtra small display example]

Can you see how the width of the input is auto in the first image

Comment: Not very clear what you're asking..

Comment: The class `col-xs-12` meaning full width for even the most narrow screen. You can set multiple grid classes on an element but as the question is asked it is very unclear what you really want. Please elaborate the question. (Media queries is built into BS3 and is selected with the middle part of the grid class name (xs, sm,md..)).

Comment: In case the screen size is xs take full width; else take whatever natural width you render. But if I use "col-xs-12 col-sm-4" then a certain width will be set for sm or larger displays, which I don't want. Shall I paste some code?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add something like

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min){
  .col-sm-auto {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

and then add this class to you element.

Or the second approach would be to have two different placeholders for different kind of screens.

For example:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs-block">Some content for extra small screens</div>
<span class="hidden-xs">Some content for small, medium and large screens</div>
```

Comment: Thanx I'll give it a try, but I generally think hidden-xs and visibile-xs should only be used if the element shouldn't/should exists for certain display sizes, not to customize width setting

Comment: yes, sure, I just gave a second option since your question didn't have alot of details :) Sometimes it can give some hint with ideas.

Comment: Thank you, it didn't work at first so I put off for later.. now I took sometime with it, and @screen-sm-min seemed to be the issue, so I changed it to 789px now it's working but I'm having some padding issues, and in my progressing layouts the issue get's more complicated. But thanx a lot